# Jquery Ajax Uncaught SyntaxError : Unepected Token )

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have setup some Jquery / Ajax pagination within my Asp.net MVC page based on an online article I found. It works for the first paging click but then I get the following error and no subsequent paging attempts will work (and the same error is reported in the console) :

Uncaught SyntaxError : Unexpected token )

The Jquery code in my razor view is as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    $(".page-number").on("click", function() {
        var page = parseInt($(this).html());
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ProductReview")',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                "id": @Model.Product.ProductID,
                "page": page
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#review-list").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

This calls an action in my controller which returns a partial view (html) and then the jQuery code should replace an entire section of my document marked by the div id, so also in my razor view I have :

```
<div id="review-list">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_ProductReview", Model.Reviews ); }
</div>
```

In my partial view the pagination links are as follows :

```
@for (int i = 1; i <= Model.Reviews.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
  <a class="page-number" href="javascript:void();">@i</a>
}
```

I can't determine if it is an error with the jQuery code itself, or what is being returned causes an issue - as I say the first click of a paging link works at the page, although the error shows in the console, and any subsequent clicks do nothing other that generate the error.

Update : it seems this works :

```
<a class="page-number" style="margin-right:10px;" href="javascript:void(0)">@i</a>
```

Comment: Did you look at what is being returned? Does the error message point to something in the code when you click on it in the console?

Comment: Do you get a line number on the error?

Comment: No it doesn't point me to anything in terms of a line number that's why I'm a bit stumped. What is returned is basic html.

Comment: just noticed that in the debugger next to the error it has VM245:1 - when I click on the it goes to a new windows and shows "void();" with the brackets underlines red?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it :

```
<a class="page-number" href="javascript:void(0)">@i</a>
```

Comment: You can choose your own answer as correct, which'll help other people with the same issue.